# How to popup a dialog box in Page Load

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, code-behind

I have make a dialogbox as shown below in aspx:

```
<div id="IsAccountingOk" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblIsAccountingOkHeader" runat="server" Text="Kassekladde:" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label><br /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="Der skal først vælges regnskabsår!"></asp:Label><br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnIsAccountingOK" runat="server" Text="Ok" OnClick="btnIsAccountingOK_Click"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

and styled as shown below:

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover {
    background: #00d9ff;
}
```

My question is: How can I popup this dialogbox by code behind in Page_Load - without making a click on a button by the user?

Maybe it can be done via JavaScript.

I have also tried the following in javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#IsAccountingOk').show();
});
```

But when I use the abovementioned method - everything on the DIV is blocked - and that was not the intention :-(

For further information I can tell that I have got it to work via a button as shown below:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnIsAccountingOk" Text="Der skal først vælges et regnskabsår" runat="server" PostBackUrl="#IsAccountingOk"/><br />
```

Further information: I have added the following line i sitepage.master:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

And it has helped a lot.

But

Thanks in advance.
Regards Michael

Comment: After page load can call pop up model window function

Comment: @vadivela Thanks for writing - but how can i call it in a window function? Do you have an example?

Comment: Its not window function your popup model function or script

Comment: can you share demo for your code?

Comment: @vadivela Thanks for writing again - but I can call a dialogbox by clicking on a button - but I don't know howto call it by code behind - so I don't know howto make this demo :-(

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ $("#yourmodel").trigger('click'); }); Can you replace target id

Comment: @vadivela I'm so sorry - but I cant get it to work - I have tried to make this with nu success:

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () { $("#btnIsAccountingOk").trigger('click'); });
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

There is not an event handler to handle when page is loading..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //code here
});
```

You can use $(document).ready() it will run code when DOM is ready and it won't wait for window loaded(images,iframes...)